# Ambiguity in the @sys.date-time entity

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've noticed some ambiguity in the @sys.date-time entity.  It appears that there is no way to discern between "today" and "today at noon" since both will resolve to a date in the format "yyyy-mm-ddT12:00:00-z" (a.k.a noon). However, they are different requests. One is asking about a whole day and the other a point in time. I would have liked if "whole day" requests sent a time of midnight or something. Is there an easy way to figure out whether the user asked for a day vs a time? Naturally, there are the other entity types which you can assume represent either a date or time, but I want to allow users to be able to ask for either, which I assume the date-time type was meant for. Thanks.

EDIT:

Based on the [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#api_v2) for the date-time entity, the response can be in the format of a string or object.  Upon further experimentation, I've noticed that it's a bit ambiguous which statements result in the string form being returned.  Statements like "today", "tomorrow", or "3pm" result in the string form, but "today at 3pm" returns the object form. I got a bit excited when I noticed that "today" and "tomorrow" and dates like "October 1" all return the string date, but my hopes were dashed when I discovered that times without dates also return a string. So, close, but not quite what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `today` is designed in such a way to point at the noon time as its the middle of the day which is g similar to geolocation when we provide lat, lon values and the pointer point to the middle of the approximate area.

Now to differentiate between `today` and `today at noon`, I made this Composite/Enum Entity and got the following results. In the webhook you may require to do some more parsing as you can see the result contains nested Key Values in JSON format. So, based on this JSON, you may be able to identify if the user is saying `today` or `today at noon`. You may use Date-Format NPM module (if using Node Client) to parse these string dates to objects.

**Entity**
[image]

**Tests**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I hope this helps your case.